# No such modules in Swift but the .swift is present

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am not able to import a swift NSManaged subclass to any other swift source code file. I created one Entity and then i created NSManaged subclass for that entity.
But i am not able to import that file to any other source code file. I might be missing some settings in the Xcode.
 Please check this image.
 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't write imports for source files, only for libraries and frameworks. Your class `USer` should be available. Btw, check it's spelling

Comment: I checked the spellings and directory. I couldnt find what is causing this issue. And i want to use the NSManagedObject Subclass so that i can easily access the attributes

Comment: I already wrote that in `Swift` you shouldn't import your source files. Remove line `import USer` - it's already included.

Comment: Oh Thanks  katleta3000! If i understood it